# ProcessBuilder unable to find Kotlin in path

Tags: java, process, kotlin

When I run:

```
new ProcessBuilder("kotlinc", "-help").start();
```

I get the error: **Cannot run program "kotlinc": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**

I've tried:

- If I check my path from windows, it contains `C:\Apps\kotlinc\bin`, and when I open explorer at that location, there's a file named `kotlinc`.
- If I open `cmd.exe` anywhere, and run `kotlinc`, it works just fine.
- If I print out my environment:

  `System.out.print(new ProcessBuilder("kotlinc", "-help").environment().get("Path"));`

  it contains `C:\Apps\kotlinc\bin`
- If I run `new ProcessBuilder("python3", "file.py").start()`, it works just fine.
- Rebooting my machine

Changing `kotlinc` to use the full file path is *not* an acceptable solution, as this is being run across multiple computers and platforms.

As far as I can tell, everything is setup correctly.

**Why can't I run `kotlinc` from `ProcessBuilder`?**

Comment: Have you tried launching eclipse with clean `eclipse -clean`, may be eclipse reading environment variables from cache

Comment: Can you just print help `kotlinc -help`, just to proof that this is not a problem with file.kt?

Comment: Just another thing to check: see the execution permissions for `kotlinc` in file system.

Comment: @Saravana I have the same problem whether I run it from IntelliJ or from the command line.

Comment: @IRus good idea, but still occurs.  Updated my question regardless.

Comment: @hotkey I've done very little with permissions so I'm not sure what to do here, but in the file properties, I've given every group every permission.  I've also tried running the project with admin `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kotlinc` is actually a batch file (`kotlinc.bat`), not a binary file. Therefore, you need to start it by executing the command `cmd /c kotlinc`.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you!  Will `cmd /c kotlinc` work on all platforms?